# How to create messaging module using telegram api in flutter

Tags: flutter, telegram

I want to create a messaging module using telegram api in my flutter application. What I want to do is, I want to create a UI like messaging and I want to message telegram users using my module in my application. Is it possible? Any help or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. There is a [TeleDart package](https://pub.dev/packages/teledart). You can use it. You will need a Telegram API token. And then you can use it like this:

```
import 'package:teledart/teledart.dart';
import 'package:teledart/telegram.dart';
import 'package:teledart/model.dart';

void main() {
  var teledart = TeleDart(Telegram('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'), Event());

  teledart.start().then((me) => print('${me.username} is initialised'));

  teledart
      .onMessage(keyword: 'Fight for freedom')
      .listen((message) => message.reply('Stand with Hong Kong'));
  
}
```

Comment: Hi Akif, just to be sure, it's a bot or it's like simple messaging app? like we have  whatsapp in which we can send/receive message from users.